# Ember datetime in the url

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, momentjs, pikaday

I have a controller with property:

```
vFrom: window.moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
```

I'm using this property in a route inside `queryParams` of `ember-cli-pagination`

```
vFrom:{
  refreshModel: true
},
```

I can change this date via a `ember-pikaday`, I set the init date in the controller `vFrom: window.moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD')` and then use it in datepicker component:

```
{{pikaday-input useUTC=true value=vFrom class="form-control"}}
```

Which then triggers model refresh on date change (which is what I want).

The problem is that I end up with a date variable in the URL `?vFrom=Fri Mar 25 2016 01%3A00%3A00 GMT%2B0100 (CET)` which is not working in all browsers (and moment warns me about this in the console) and ends up breaking my app.

How can I change the date format that ends up in the URL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with observers:

```
 datef: Ember.observer('vFrom', function(){
    var fromD = this.get('vFrom');
    if( fromD instanceof Date )
    {
      this.set('vFrom', window.moment.utc(fromD).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    }
  }),
  datet: Ember.observer('vTo', function(){
    var fromD = this.get('vTo');
    if( fromD instanceof Date )
    {
      this.set('vTo', window.moment.utc(fromD).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which I think is better than using observer.

`{{pikaday-input useUTC=true value=datef class="form-control"}}`

```
queryParams: ['vFrom'],
datef: Ember.computed('vFrom', {
    get() {
        return moment(this.get('vFrom')).format();
    },
    set(key, value) {
        this.set('vFrom', moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        return value;
    }
})
```